# What does &handler mean in the code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void handler (int sig)
{
   printf ("Got signal %d\n", sig);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct sigaction act;

  memset (&act, '\0', sizeof(act));

  // Use the sa_sigaction field because
  // the handler has two additional parameters
  act.sa_handler = &handler;

  if (sigaction(SIGHUP, &act, NULL) < 0) {
     perror ("sigaction");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL) < 0) {
     perror ("sigaction");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  while (1) sleep (10);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am a bit confused about "&handler" . What does it mean here? I am new to signal and really hope someone can give me a hint on how it works. Any help would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: It is a function pointer, it will be called when the signal specified by your `sigaction` is sent.

Comment: With functions, `&function` and just `function` mean the same thing — a pointer to the function.  The `&` is unnecessary.  Were I reviewing the code, the `&` would be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Man page of [SIGACTION](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) :

> The sigaction structure is defined as something like:
>
> ```
>        struct sigaction {
>            void     (*sa_handler)(int);
>            void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
>            sigset_t   sa_mask;
>            int        sa_flags;
>            void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
>        };
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>    `sa_handler` specifies the action to be associated with signum and may
>    be SIG_DFL for the default action, SIG_IGN to ignore this signal, or
>    a pointer to a signal handling function.  This function receives the
>    signal number as its only argument.
> ```
>
> [...]

Here, `sa_handler` is a pointer to a function and hold the address of `handler()` function.

Comment: Yep. But what does the "int sig"  refers to ? If I use a function pointer I can't pass any argument in right ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html),

```
struct sigaction {
           void     (*sa_handler)(int);
           void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
           sigset_t   sa_mask;
           int        sa_flags;
           void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
       };
```

The `sa_handler` is a function pointer that must point to a signal handling function.

> sa_handler specifies the action to be associated with signum and may
>          be SIG_DFL for the default action, SIG_IGN to ignore this signal, or
>          a pointer to a signal handling function.  This function receives the
>          signal number as its only argument.